# redirect to unique page

Tags: php

when I log in...i want to it to find my new $_SESSION variable and then reload into that page with all the selected data. But instead of http://www.theqlick.com/findFriends/lesson.php?username=noahtheteacher

I get this instead: http://theqlick.com/findFriends/lesson.php?username=%3C?%20echo%20noahtheteacher;%20?%3E

Why is that? It isn't loading the correct page either...my code is below

The top of the page:

```
      $new_user = $_SESSION['user_login'];

        if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
       echo "";
        }
      else
       {
     echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=lesson.php?username=<? echo $new_user; ?>\">";

         }
```

The login actual html code:

```
        <h2>If your a teacher, login below ...</h2>
        <form action="lessons_login.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
            <input type="text" size="40" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="auto-clear" title="Username ..." /><p />
            <input type="text" size="40" name="password_login" id="password_login" value="Password ..." /><p />
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account">
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url='lesson.php?username=$new_user'\" >";

Answer (score 1):

As @nelson suggested, you've got  tags inside an already parsed line. Therefore the interpreter isn't parsing that as an opening and closing tag but rather as characters to be echoed.

I would further recommend that you use double quotes to open and close your line, and then single quotes inside of that so you don't have to escape them. Then, put {} around your variables to ensure proper parsing.

For instance,

```
<?php
echo "<a href='www.example.com'>{$my_variable}</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=lesson.php?username=<? echo $new_user; ?>\">";
```

for this one:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=lesson.php?username=$new_user\">";
```

As you don't need to use the `<? echo $new_user; ?>` syntax because that syntax is used to embedded php code inside html code, not in PHP itself as you were doing.